# When and why would the C linker exclude unused symbols?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm performing some tests with `gcc` to understand the rule(s) by which it intelligently excludes unused symbols.

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  return 0;
}
```

.

```
// bar.c

int bar()
{
  return 42;
}
```

.

```
> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> gcc -c bar.c
> gcc -g main.c bar.o 
> nm a.out | grep "foo\|bar"
000000000040111f T bar
0000000000401106 T foo
```

Above, I've compiled `bar.o`, and linked it with `a.out` while compiling `main.c`.
Listing `a.out`'s symbols show that both unused functions - `foo()` and `bar()` - are included in the executable.

```
> ar -r libbar.a bar.o
ar: creating libbar.a
> gcc -g main.c -L ./ -lbar
> nm a.out | grep "foo\|bar"
0000000000401106 T foo
```

Above, I've archived `bar.o` to `libbar.a`, and recreated `a.out`, this time linking with `libbar.a` instead of `bar.o`. This time around, unused function `foo()` is still present, but `bar()` is not.

From this experiment, I might surmise the following "rules":

1. Symbols linked from object files are always present in executables. (Perhaps this explains why `foo()` is always present: is there a temporary/anonymous `main.o` that's created? If so, it would include `foo()`)
2. If an executable is linked with a *library*, `gcc` will intelligently figure out unnecessary symbols to exclude.

The above are my hypotheses based on this experiment - but how correct is it? If someone is knowledgeable with the intricacies of how linking works, I'd be grateful for some background information explaining the whys and wherefores of what's going on.

Comment: Is this question about ELF and th GNU gABI? Different targets vary quite a bit in this area.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer - sorry, I'm not very familiar with those terms. I vaguely remember ELF is a "format" of the memory layout of an executable(?) I added the output of my "`gcc --version`" in case that answers your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mostly correct with the caveat that static-library linking doesn't really have per-symbol granularity. It has per-member-object-file granularity.

**Example:**

If the static library contains files:

```
a.o 
    foo
    bar
b.o 
    baz
```

and an undefined reference to `foo` needs to be resolved, `a.o` will be brought in, and with it the `bar` symbol as well.

You can get the effect of per symbol granularity when you compile with  `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections` and then link with `-Wl,--gc-sections` (gc stands for garbage-collect), but bear in mind that the compiler/linker options are gcc/clang-specific and that they have some minor performance/code-size cost.

`-ffunction-sections` puts each function in its own section (sort of like its own object file) and `-fdata-sections` does the same thing for externally visible global variables. `-Wl,--gc-sections` then causes a garbage collector to run after the object files are linked as usual, and the garbage collector removes all sections (=>symbols) that are unreachable.

(`-ffunction-sections` is also useful if you want `size -A the_objectfile.o` to give you function sizes and if you also want those functions sizes to
not slightly fluctuate based on the position of the functions (due to alignment requirements).)

Comment: Thank you; you've answered my question. Do you happen to know _why_ the linker works differently when linking objects vs. static libs? I.e why does linking against an object result in unconditional inclusion of all its symbols, but linking against a static lib result in per-member-object-file exclusion of unused symbols? I'm just curious to understand rationale behind this behavior, if you happen to be aware of it.

Comment: @StoneThrow IDK. I think it's because object files aren't guaranteed to have an index and including them unconditionally avoids the need for a second pass through each object file that wouldn't be skipped, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `--gc-sections` is not really "per-symbol granularity" of linking. Linking libraries is still on a per-object-file granularity (this can make a big difference in the presence of weak references or weak definitions with strong replacements), but *after the set of objects being linked is fully resolved*, the per-function/per-data-object section references are garbage-collected to drop the ones which are unreachable.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the clarification. That part of my answer was a little sloppy. I've edited your info in.